# Scroll to animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created simple link animation to scroll, this link may be link to scroll in section in the same page or link to external URL, the problem that if you clicked on the button ("section 4") You will find a strange movement this was the first problem.

---

**Second Problem:** that if the user click on button more than once then click on another button, the scroll will not work until the previous click finished:

**My code is below:**

```js
 $(".links a").click(function () {
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top
            }, 1400)
        })
```

```css
.links {
    width:600px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    padding:20px;
}
.links a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px 20px;
    border:1px solid #0094ff;
}
.section {
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    margin:300px auto 600px;
    background-color:#0094ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="links">
        <a href="#section1">Section 1</a>
        <a href="#section2">Section 2</a>
        <a href="#section3">Section 3</a>
        <a href="#section4">Section 4</a>
        <a href="http://google.com">External Link</a>
    </div>
    <div id="section1" class="section"></div>
    <div id="section2" class="section"></div>
    <div id="section3" class="section"></div>
    <div id="section4" class="section"></div>
```

**Note:** please don't recommended me to use any plugin i'd like to know more and more about Javascript

Comment: Not sure if I understand, especially what's wrong with clicking on `#section4` but does this address it or the second issue? Sounds like you just need to call `$.stop()` before `$.animate()` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWpeyJ

Comment: You can usually fix the second problem you mention by using `.stop()` so your code would read `$("html, body").stop().animate({...`

Comment: Thank you but about the first problem :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `e.preventDefault()`.

Pass the event argument into the click event by changing your function from:

```
$(".links a").click(function () {
```

to

```
$(".links a").click(function (e) {
```

Now you can edit the default event of the click. You can do this with `preventDefault` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault.

Secondly, you can use [stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) to fix the animation.

```js
 $(".links a").click(function (e) {
  if ($(this).attr("href").charAt(0) == "#") {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("html, body").stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top
    }, 1400)
  }
});
```

```css
.links{
                width:600px;
                position:fixed;
                top:0;
                padding:20px;
            }
            .links a{
                display:inline-block;
                padding:10px 20px;
                border:1px solid #0094ff;
            }
            .section{
                width:400px;
                height:200px;
                margin:300px auto 600px;
                background-color:#0094ff;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="links">
        <a href="#section1">Section 1</a>
        <a href="#section2">Section 2</a>
        <a href="#section3">Section 3</a>
        <a href="#section4">Section 4</a>
        <a href="http://google.com">External Link</a>
    </div>
    <div id="section1" class="section"></div>
    <div id="section2" class="section"></div>
    <div id="section3" class="section"></div>
    <div id="section4" class="section"></div>
```

Comment: using preventDefault will prevent open the external link

Comment: I Suggest that check if the href is start with do preventDefault But I don't how to do that

Comment: Hey @MichaelNeas I'm sure you've figured this out by now, but you can check if a link href begins with # really easily. As all of your internal links do, we can trigger the function only on these links by wrapping everything in `if ($(this).attr("href").charAt(0) == "#") {`. This is saying, if the href attribute of this (the clicked item) has a character at the beginning which is a hash, do the following.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery stop()` Method

```js
 $(".links a").click(function (e) {
  var hrefLink =  $(e.target).attr("href");
  var  hrefSplitted = hrefLink.split("#");
  if(hrefSplitted.length == 2){ 
     e.preventDefault();
  };
           /* if(! $(e.target).is('.links a:last') ){ 
               e.preventDefault();
             }*/
            
             $("html, body").stop();
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top
            }, 1400)
        })
```

```css
.links{
                width:600px;
                position:fixed;
                top:0;
                padding:20px;
            }
            .links a{
                display:inline-block;
                padding:10px 20px;
                border:1px solid #0094ff;
            }
            .section{
                width:400px;
                height:200px;
                margin:300px auto 600px;
                background-color:#0094ff;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="links">
        <a href="#section1">Section 1</a>
        <a href="#section2">Section 2</a>
        <a href="#section3">Section 3</a>
        <a href="#section4">Section 4</a>
        <a href="http://google.com">External Link</a>
    </div>
    <div id="section1" class="section" style="background:red;"></div>
    <div id="section2" class="section"  style="background:blue;"></div>
    <div id="section3" class="section" style="background:green;"></div>
    <div id="section4" class="section" style="background:yellow;"></div>
```

Comment: using preventDefault will prevent to open external link

Comment: I Suggest that check if the href is start with do preventDefault But I don't how to do that

Comment: Thanks for pointing that I have added a check for that,Checking if it is the last anchor tag.  Updated snippet

Comment: thank you my friend, but external link button may be the second button in the DOM I need my code is flexible so we can check if the href start with # or not if the anachor href is start with # call prevent default :) 
thank you again

Comment: Then you can take the href from that tag.console.log($(e.target).attr(''href")); This will output the href of that tag.split it and check if the # exits

Answer (score 0):

you can use `e.preventDefault()` Method Will Prevent in This Example `e.preventDefault()` will prevent the link from following the URL.

```
$(".links a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

But `e.preventDefault()`It will cause another problem because if you have external link You will not be able to open it so what is the solution, the solution The solution is to test the value of href, if the href is start with "#" call `e.preventDefault()`:

```
$(".links a").click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).attr("href").charAt(0) == "#") {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

You can also check if the link is external link, will open in new tab:

```
$(".links a").click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).attr("href").charAt(0) == "#") {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        $($(this)).attr("target","_blank")
    }
});
```

**Finally** you can prevent multiple clicks using `stop()` method.

**Here the final code:**

```js
$(".links a").click(function (e) {
            if (this.getAttribute("href").charAt(0) == "#") {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("html, body").stop();
                $("html, body").animate({
                    scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top
                }, 1400)
            }
             else {
            $($(this)).attr("target","_blank")
        }
        })
```

```css
.links{
  width:600px;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  padding:20px;
}
.links a{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 20px;
  border:1px solid #0094ff;
}
.section{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  margin:300px auto 600px;
  background-color:#0094ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="links">
    <a href="#section1">Section 1</a>
    <a href="#section2">Section 2</a>
    <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">External Link</a>
    <a href="#section3">Section 3</a>
    <a href="#section4">Section 4</a>
</div>
<div id="section1" class="section"></div>
<div id="section2" class="section"></div>
<div id="section3" class="section"></div>
<div id="section4" class="section"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you it's what i need Thank you again MoHamed

Comment: Your answer is incomplete. You should provide explanations about event bubbling and jQuery animation queues. 

https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/ // 
https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html // 
https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/ // 
https://learn.jquery.com/effects/queue-and-dequeue-explained/ // 
https://api.jquery.com/stop/ // 
https://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/

Comment: Thank you but mu basic language is not English you can edit my answer